# Unwanted space between letters in tabular cell

Tags: tables, makecell

I am using below code,

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Performance comparison of CMOS VCO with the state-of-the-art}
\label{tab:3_3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
\small
  \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}| }
    \hline

        \thead{References} &  
    \thead{Jalil \\ et al. \\ \cite{ref2}} &   
    \thead{Chanchan \\et al. \\ \cite{ref33}}  &
    \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref34}}  &
    \thead{Sakka \\et al. \\ \cite{ref35}}  &
    \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref36}}  &
    \thead{Chien \\et al. \\ \cite{ref37}}  &
    \thead{This \\Work}  \\ \hline

         \makecell[ct]Technology (nm)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]No of Stages&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Supply Voltage (V)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]DC Power (mW)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Tuning Range (GHz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Tuning Range (\%)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Phase Noise (dBc/Hz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Offset Frequency (MHz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]FOM (dBc/Hz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]Area (\si{\um^2} )&&&&&&&\\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

Output is like,

[image]

**I wonder why the contents for column `Reference` are showing in such wired format. (unwanted spaces between letters in same word). How can I resolve this?**

Comment: `\makecell[ct]`  takes an argument, which means it is usually used as in `\makecell[ct]{Technology (nm)}`. If you write `\makecell[ct] Technology (nm)`, TeX just grabs the very first bit (token) from the following text, so it effectively sees `\makecell[ct]{T}echnology (nm)`, which may give weird results. You need to fix that in the complete first column. But I'm wondering whether you need the `\makecell[ct]`s there at all. What happens you if leave them out?

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use `\makecell` here, as you have paragraph mode cells.  I defined  a short cut for `\newline` to control line breaks in the first column. I also improved a bit the general layout, loading the `caption` package to have a better spacing between caption and table, and made the outer rules thicker:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
    \usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
    \renewcommand{\theadset} {\bfseries}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{chemformula}
\let\nl\newline

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Performance comparison of CMOS VCO with the state-of-the-art}
\label{tab:3_3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\centering\small
\small
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 1pt}>{\centering}p{2.1cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}!{\vrule width 1pt}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
        \thead{References} &
    \thead{Jalil \\ et al. \\ \cite{ref2}} &
    \thead{Chanchan \\et al. \\ \cite{ref33}} &
    \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref34}} &
    \thead{Sakka \\et al. \\ \cite{ref35}} &
    \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref36}} &
    \thead{Chien \\et al. \\ \cite{ref37}} &
    \thead{This \\Work} \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
         Technology\nl (nm)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
       No of\nl Stages&&&&&&&\\ \hline
        Supply \nl Voltage (V)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         DC Power\nl (mW)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
        Tuning\nl Range(GHz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         Tuning\nl Range (\%)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         Phase Noise\nl (dBc/Hz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         Offset\nl Frequency (MHz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         FOM \nl(dBc/Hz)&&&&&&&\\ \hline
         Area\nl (\si{\um^2} )&&&&&&&\\
         \Xhline{1pt}
     \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use ragged right?

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  As far as I remember, I tested this possibility, while keeping two lines per cell, and in some of them, the unit was alone on the second line. I found this lonely little unit looked really weird.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can guess (you not provide contents of table body cells), you have enough space for writing text in the first column in one line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\theadset{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\let\nl\newline

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Performance comparison of CMOS VCO with the state-of-the-art}
\label{tab:3_3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\centering
\small
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        !{\vrule width 1pt}l | *{6}{l |}l !{\vrule width 1pt}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
\thead{References} 
    &   \thead{Jalil \\ et al. \\ \cite{ref2}} 
        &   \thead{Chanchan \\et al. \\ \cite{ref33}} 
            &   \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref34}} 
                &   \thead{Sakka \\et al. \\ \cite{ref35}} 
                    &   \thead{Kumar \\et al. \\ \cite{ref36}} 
                        &   \thead{Chien \\et al. \\ \cite{ref37}} 
                            &   \thead{This \\Work} 
                                \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
Technology\nl (nm)
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
No of Stages
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Supply Voltage (V)
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 DC Power\ (mW)
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Tuning Range(GHz)
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 Tuningl Range (\%)
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 Phase Noisel (dBc/Hz)
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 Offset Frequency (MHz)
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 FOM (dBc/Hz)
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 Area (\si{\um^2})
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]